# Geofences - addOnCompleteListener(this) not working

Tags: java, android, location, android-geofence

I am trying to build a geofencing app. I found a sample on GitHub and referenced that for the majority of my project. If it is of any significance, this code was included in the MainActivity in the sample, but I have it in another activity.

On the addGeofences method, I get an error that says:

> addOnCompleteListener (com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener) in Task cannot be applied to (my package name)

I have scoured posts and almost all are about Firebase. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
private void addGeofences() {
    if (!checkPermissions()) {
        showSnackbar(getString(R.string.insufficient_permissions));
        return;
    }

    mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
            .addOnCompleteListener(this);
}
```

Note: I also get the same error in the removeGeofences method.

Comment: Are you implementing `OnCompleteListener<Void>` in `this` class?

Comment: hey, i already found and implemented the solution. As you said, I had to implement the OnCompleteListener<Void>

Comment: Then please post the answer and close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out this problem...I forgot to implement the `OnCompleteListener<Void>` in the class declaration. The corrected code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnCompleteListener<Void>{
```